# How to write this recursive query correctly in the SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, recursive-query

I write a recursive query. Problem: a recursive query that show chain management employees that leads to a particular employee('Maria Cameron' with `empid`=8).Output should be like this:[image: output]

and `HR.Employees` is here:
[image: table]

and my query is here:

```
with Managers as
(

SELECT empid, mgrid, firstname,lastname
FROM HR.Employees as h
where mgrid IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT e.empid,e.mgrid,e.firstname,e.lastname
FROM HR.Employees as e INNER JOIN Managers m 
ON (e.mgrid = m.empid)
)
 SELECT *
 FROM Managers
 where firstname='Maria' and lastname='Cameron' and empid=8
```

but this query don't operate correctly and my output is:
[image]

Comment: "but this query can't operate correctly."  -- can you elaborate?  What is not working correctly?

Comment: @roryap:  
I edit my question and put output there

Answer (score 1):

This line here is not correct:

```
with Managers as
(

SELECT empid, mgrid, firstname,lastname
FROM HR.Employees as h
where 
*******
```

Where what?

```
WHERE h.mgrid IS NULL
```